# PHP Ajuda com hd 50000 imagens

Tags: php

Como fazer em php carregar 50000 imagens de um hd

meu codigo

```
<?php
$imgdir = '/media/hd-ext/Images/JPG/'; //Minha Pasta
$allowed_types = array('jpeg'); //Tipo de extensao
$dimg = opendir($imgdir);//Abre o Diretorio
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg))
{
  if( in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types) OR
      in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-4)),$allowed_types) )
/*Se o arquivo for uma imagem, adicione-o array*/
  {$a_img[] = $imgfile;}
}
echo "<ul>";

 $totimg = count($a_img);  //Conta o taotal de imagens
//Echo nas imagens dentro do li.
 for($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){echo "<li><img src='" . $imgdir . $a_img[$x] . "' /></li>";}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

separando por data igual ao google photos

Erro! carrega as imagens mas demora 3 dias para carregar todas as imagens!

Comment: É coisa demais para um browser carregar e mostrar, você precisaria paginar essa lista.

Answer (score 1):

50000 imagens é uma quantidade absurda de dados pra um browser carregar, faça um gerenciamento para que seja carregado uma determinada quantidade por vez, senão o carregamento de tudo isso em 3 dias será o tempo mínimo gasto rs